# form action attribute set to?

Tags: php, html

When is the need to set from action attribute to ? like this

```
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="?" method="post">
<div>
<label for="joketext">Type your joke here:</label>
<textarea id="joketext" name="joketext" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
</div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Add"/></div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: To progress the submitted value in same page

Comment: @TamilSelvan This is just one purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The need for setting the form action is so that the form can be submitted to whatever action you dictate, if you leave the action blank then the form will submit to itself (the same page it is on)

If you had a form handler which was not visible but handled all the processing, then you could define the handler address (url) in the form action or even send the data to another page if you so choose.

And wherever you sent it to, a form handler or itself or another page, that would take care of the data and deal with accordingly, as you so choose.

Answer (score 1):

If you use:

```
<form action="myform.php" method="post">
```

Then the form redirects to `myform.php` And in this file there is the code that checks the form.

If you use:

```
<form action="myform.php?check" method="post">
```

Then the form redirects to `myform.php` but it also adds check to the `$_GET` array.

So you can write a piece of code that only works if there is a `check` element in your `$_GET` array.

```
if(isset($_GET['check']))
{
    // your code here
}
```

In PHP every element after `?` is a member of the `$_GET` array
For example: `http://www.example.com?product_id=1&product_name=acme` means that the $_GET array currenty has two elements:

```
product_id
product_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the below link should help.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

It allows you to specify where you want to post your form data

Answer (score -1):

when you want form data to be stored, you can set it to a php file and save the data to a database, text file, or xml.